# phpunit "No tests executed"

Tags: php, phpunit

I can't solve the problem with testing in PHPUnit. This is my code, and there's sommething wrong with it. This is the Annual percentage rate calculation ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annual_percentage_rate ).

In cmd:

```
    C:\Users\Shambler\Downloads\test-taeg-senior\test-taeg>phpunit
PHP Warning:  Module 'oci8' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Module 'oci8' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHPUnit 3.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from C:\Users\Shambler\Downloads\test-taeg-senior\test-taeg\phpunit.xml



Time: 74 ms, Memory: 2.00MB

No tests executed!

C:\Users\Shambler\Downloads\test-taeg-senior\test-taeg>
```

Don't think about Oracle module, it's another story. I ran "phpunit" after "composer install".

project/tests/test-general.php:

```
    <?php

use MotorK\{ Rate, Tae, Taeg };

class TestTaeg extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase {

    /**
     * Example from http://www.calcolatoremutui.it/tan-e-taeg/
     */
    public function test_tae() {
        $obj = Tae::init( 5, 12 );

        $this->assertEquals( 5.116, round( $obj->calculate(), 3 ) );

        $this->expectOutputString( '5.116 %' );
        echo $obj;
    }

    /**
     * Example from http://www.calcolatoremutui.it/tan-e-taeg/
     */
    public function test_rate() {
        $obj = Rate::init( 100000, 5, 12, 20 );

        $this->assertEquals( 659.96, round( $obj->calculate(), 2 ) );

        $this->expectOutputString( '659.96 €' );
        echo $obj;
    }

    /**
     * Example from http://www.calcolatoremutui.it/tan-e-taeg/
     */
    public function test_taeg() {
        $obj = Taeg::init( 99000, 5, 661.96, 12, 20 );

        $this->assertEquals( 5.281, round( $obj->calculate(), 3 ) );

        $this->expectOutputString( '5.281 %' );
        echo $obj;
    }
}
```

project/phpunit.xml

```
<phpunit
bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
backupGlobals="false"
colors="true"
convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
>
<testsuite name="Internal tests">
    <directory prefix="test-" suffix=".php">./tests/</directory>
</testsuite>
<groups>
    <include>
        <group>default</group>
    </include>
</groups>
<filter>
    <whitelist>
        <directory suffix=".php">./includes/</directory>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
```

I can't solve it, tried it many times :(

Answer (score 6):

The suffix (not the prefix) of a test case class' name must be  `Test`. And the sourcecode file's name must match the class name.

In your example, you probably want `TaegTest` (instead of `TestTaeg`) declared in `TaegTest.php` (instead of `test-general.php`).

Also note that the version of PHPUnit you use has reached its end of life years ago. Read [this](https://phpunit.de/getting-started-with-phpunit.html) to get started working with a recent version of PHPUnit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for developing PHPUnit. Unfortunately, I'm not able to modify test-general.php and phpunit.xml files and I can only use methods so the test can execute. I created "MotorK" folder and Tae.php inside, cause of `use MotorK\{ Rate, Tae, Taeg };` but nothing had changed :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to create include folder and under that you need to create MotorK folder and then you should create classes. You should have following directory structure:

> test-taeg/includes/MotorK

```
test-taeg
+
|
+-include
|
++ --MotorK
|
+++ ---Rate.php
|
+++ ---Tae.php
|
+++ ---Taeg.php
```

`MotorK` should be your `namespace`.